# Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to spawn multiple daemons. [Android Studio 4.1]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I can't figure out what this warning is refering to. How is this triggered?

```
                Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
                More info...
                Select a JDK from the File System
                Do not show this warning again
```

What is the solution or steps to do things correctly?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately no!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instruct Gradle to use Java from different location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432643/how-to-instruct-gradle-to-use-java-from-different-location)

Comment: I started to have this error with Android Studio Arctic Fox where I set JDK 11 under the gradle setting page, but ignored the system setting of JAVA_HOME, which still pointed to JDK 8.  I changed JAVA_HOME to JDK 11, and the error is gone.