# Uninstalled BumbleBee, installed Flamingo, but now encountering Gradle daemon spawning issue in Android Studio - how to fix?

Tags: gradle, android-asynctask, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-flamingo

I have this problem in Android studio after unistalling Bumblebee and installing Flamingo.

> Multiple Gradle daemons might be spawned because the Gradle JDK and `JAVA_HOME` locations are different.
>
> Project 'My Application' is using the following JDK location when running Gradle: `'C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jbr'`
>
> The system environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is: `'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19'` If you dont need to use different paths (or if `JAVA_HOME` is undefined), you can avoid spawning multiple daemons by setting `JAVA_HOME` and the JDK location to the same path.

I tried to Install the new Android Studio Flamingo Version after successfully uninstalling the BumbleBee version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to instruct Gradle to use Java from different location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432643/how-to-instruct-gradle-to-use-java-from-different-location)